How to detected when Image in CachedNetworkImage has completed loading an image?
I have a very simple Widget.
CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.imageUrls[imageIndex],
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
             
            ),

When the image is loaded, I want to do something, like scrolling to bottom page or showing popup. But how to get event to detect that ?

Nice question.
If you take a look at the docs for cached_network_image, it accepts a imageBuilder, which is of type ImageWidgetBuilder - that gets called, as the docs explain:

Builder function to create an image widget. The function is called after the ImageProvider completes the image loading.

Code example:
  CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                    // do a complex task, in your example - scroll
                    // _myComplexTask();
                    // you might need to wrap in  addpostframecallback 
                    // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    //   _myComplexTask();
                    // });

                    return Container(
                      width: 250,
                      height: 250,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: imageProvider,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),

I've tested in Chrome with Network throttling enabled (meaning, slow internet) and it seems to work.

Wouldn't this fire every time  setState  is called ?

@TSR Probably. But you can set a boolean variable flag, for example, isImageLoaded
